# Is there a way to use GET and POST together?

Tags: php

I need to pass some data with these 2 methods together ( GET AND POST ).
I write this method, but I don't know if it is safe:

```
<form method="post" action="profile.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" size="40" name="title" >
<textarea name="description" rows="2" cols="30"></textarea>
<input id="starit" name="submit" value="Create" type="submit" />
</form>

<?php 
a= $_GET['id'];
b= $_POST['title'];
c= $_POST['description'];
?>
```

Is this code safe ? Or there are other ways to do that ?

Comment: Why you don't just write the Session Id into an hidden input field of your form? In the end the user could read out his session Id anyways if he browses the website's source.

Comment: Maybe he has reasons to do this like this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is not a combined GET and POST request; rather, it's a POST request with query parameters.

What you have written would be the right way. Always make sure that you get the expected fields:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'], $_POST['title'], $_POST['description']) {
  // go ahead
}
```

Btw, make sure that you escape your output:

```
<form method="post" action="profile.php?id=<?php echo rawurlencode($_SESSION['id']); ?>">
```

And if you're not uploading files, you don't need to set the `enctype` of your `<form>`.

Comment: Oh, you can use multiple variables with `isset`? :D

Comment: @ADTC yeah, returns true is all are set

Answer (score 3):

you can use both and get with REQUEST instead of GET or POST, with the same name of params it will get the "request-order" order GET and then POST by default.

http://php.net/request-order

it is in php.ini

Answer (score 1):

This is better :

```
<form method="post" action="profile.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($_SESSION['id'])); ?>">
```

Answer (score -1):

don't write method attribute in your form condition
and add **formmethod=" "** attribute in input...
for example:

```
<input type="submit" formmethod="get"  name="inputGet" value="updateGet" >
<input type="submit" formmethod="post" name="inputPost" value="updatePost" >
```

Comment: do you mean `form method` ?