# Can A Form Method Be Post And Get?

Tags: php, html, post, get

I am learning PHP and have a situation where I want the method to be `POST` to pass variables to my php and

> 1) Connect to Server
> 2) store results in a variable
> 3) Display an HTML Table

However, I later on in my syntax want to use `GET` to "recall" that variable and output the results to a CSV file.  This is what I have, but when I click the button Generate nothing happens.  Is this possible?  If not, how should I re-write the syntax to make ithappen?

```
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        End Date:<input type="date" name="end" value="<?= $_POST['end'] ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">
    </form>
</body>
<?php
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
   {
       //Connect To Server
       //Store Result Set in Variable
       //Display HTML Table
   }
?>

<form method="get">
    <button type="submit" name="csv" value="1">Generate CSV</button>
</form>
```

Comment: you don't need 2 forms. You can pass a GET argument in the action, or use sessions.

Comment: @Fred-ii- - how would I pass a get and set?

Comment: something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977874/is-there-a-way-to-use-get-and-post-together --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036858/want-to-use-both-get-and-post-methods --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749406/post-and-get-at-the-same-time-in-php

Comment: Looking at the second link you posted.  `<form action="myfile.php?var1=get1&amp;var2=get2&amp;var3=get3" method="post">` - I do not have an external php file, my php markup is all in the same file.  Would I just use the current page name then?

Comment: yes you could use the same file. Something like `action="?var1...."` etc. should work.