# trying to update the records but failing in php

Tags: php, post, mysqli, phpmyadmin, get

im trying to a update a record by getting the id of the post via $_GET then update the records through $_POST.

i already have performed the delete action through $_GET it works fine also the mysqli_fetch_assoc works fine for displaying the record for editing but the actual editing does not happens it gives a Empty error from the validation in the code in the empty check function.

i have gone through lots research but cant seem to get my head around the error , i would thank full if any one could suggest any changes in the code.

Thank you in advance!

This is the error

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in /then the long url etc/
```

Below is the code

```
<?php
 //DB Connection
  include'include/db-conn.php';
  if (isset($_POST['edit'])) {
     //Raw GET Inputs
    $raw_c_id       = $_GET['id'];

    //Cleaned Inputs
    $c_c_id         = filter_var($raw_c_id, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //Error Mwssages
    $empty      = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                <strong>Error!</strong>Field is empty please provide content!
              </div>
              ';
    $success    = '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fixed-top">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                <strong>Success!</strong> Content Added Successfully
              </div>
              ';
    $not_success  = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                    <strong>Not Success!</strong> Content Not Added Successfully
                  </div>
                  ';

      if (empty($c_c_id)) {
        echo $empty;
        exit();
        header("Location:index.php");
      }

      $update      = "UPDATE `continents` 
       SET `continent_name`='$c_c_name', `last_edited`='date(d/m/Y)'  
       WHERE `id`='$c_c_id'";
       $run_update  = mysqli_query($conn, $update);
      if (!$run_update) {
        header("Location: index.php");
        echo $not_success;

      }
      else{
        header("Location: index.php");
        echo $success;
      }
  }
 ?>
```

This is the html part

```
<div  class="panel-body">
            <form action="edit.php" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="continent_name">Continent Name</label>
                  <input required type="text" placeholder="10" class="form-control" value="<?php echo  $c_name ; ?>" name="continent_name">
                </div>
              <small>Date Added: <?php echo  $c_dated_added ; ?></small> / <small>Last Edited: <?php echo  $c_last_edited ; ?></small>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control btn-success" type="submit" name="edit" value="Submit">
                </div>
              </form>
          </div>
```

Thid the while loop

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table id="example" class="table table-hover ">
    <thead>
      <tr class="">
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Continent Name</th>
        <th>Date Added</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
            $all_continents     =   "SELECT * FROM `continents` ORDER BY `status`";

            $run                    =   mysqli_query($conn,$all_continents);

            while ($row_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)) {
                $id =   $row_result['id'];
                $c_continent_name = $row_result['continent_name'];
                $c_date_added = $row_result['date_added'];
                $c_status = $row_result['status'];

                echo "
                <tr>
                    <td>$id</td>
                    <td>$c_continent_name</td>
                    <td>$c_date_added</td>
                    <td>$c_status</td>
                    <td>
                        <a class='btn btn-info' href='edit.php?id=$id'>Edit</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a class='btn btn-danger'  href='delete.php?id=$id'>Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                ";
            }
         ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post the URL it's posting to.  I want to see the GET paramaters

Comment: show your actual url.

Comment: <a class='btn btn-info' href='edit.php?id=$id'>Edit</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use GET and POST parameters at the same time. The reason it's not working is because the GET parameter is lost when you submit your form. You need to pass it on in the form's action attribute:

```
<form action="edit.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>" method="POST">
```

Please also take a look at the advice in this post:
[Is there a way to use GET and POST together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977874/is-there-a-way-to-use-get-and-post-together)

Comment: thank you very much for you help it did work. is there any chance in looking at this code form me and let me know where i got it wrong! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53023485/kindly-have-a-look-at-this-code-and-let-me-know-where-i-got-it-wrong

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct if it resolved your issue. I will take a look at your other post.